# How to add a custom checkbox component to JIRA comments?

Tags: checkbox, customization, jira, user-permissions, jira-plugin

I need to add a checkbox item in the JIRA comments, so i could specify a permissions to view this comment for different groups of users. 
Is it possible? 
If yes, could anyone give me an advice how i can do this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure **comment visibility** in general settings, this can be either project roles or project roles and groups.

Then you can set visibility settings individually for each comment (choose project role or group).

More information: 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/commenting-on-an-issue-185729604.html
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/configuring-jira-options-185729544.html